# insert variable/function in php href

Tags: php

I have to insert the code: `<?php WPSM_Woohelper::re_show_brand_tax(); ?>`

in the <a href below:

```
$text = '<p>' . substr($content, 0, $pos[$limit]) . "..<a href='{$product_url}' class='goto_more_offer_tab button'><?php WPSM_Woohelper::re_show_brand_tax(); ?></a></p>";
```

how to do?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Echo the output of `WPSM_Woohelper::re_show_brand_tax();`:

```
$text = '<p>'
    . substr($content, 0, $pos[$limit])
    . '..<a href="' . $product_url . '" class="goto_more_offer_tab button">'
    . WPSM_Woohelper::re_show_brand_tax()
    . '</a></p>';
```

Comment: Sorry, I had to fix a few quote issues. I prefer using single quotes in php, so that I don't get into trouble with double-quotes in html.

Comment: it doesn't work, it gives me this on screen: ' . WPSM_Woohelper::re_show_brand_tax(); . '

Comment: I'm checking quotes for the fifth time now, lol. Maybe you need to check them again, too?